# android shoutcast player multiple links

Tags: android, stream, shoutcast

I am trying to update my radio shoutcast app.

It's working now, it plays a singe radio station link, if you click on the play button a stream will play on 128kbps.

What i am trying to do now is to add another station link, so i will have two buttons for each link the best will be if one stream is playing the other stream wont start.

I am using  a service for the mediaplayer.

This is what i have now.

My service:

```
public class My_Service extends Service implements OnBufferingUpdateListener {
private static final String TAG = "MyService";
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private final Handler m_handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    String url = "http://url/";
    try 
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

My main activity:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (playStop.isChecked() && UtilityClass.isInternetOn(this))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: buffering... : " +  "%");
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
            startService(new Intent(this, My_Service.class));
        }
        else if(UtilityClass.isInternetOn(this))
        {

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
            stopService(new Intent(this, My_Service.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have it working i added another service it is working but i dont know if it is the proper way